# Mixing Wordpress eCommerce site with external login based Vue Frontend Best Practices

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, dns

I am new to web development and and would like advice about what is the usual best practices to achieve what I am trying to do.

I am in charge of writing a frontend app using Vue. This frontend will require a login to access the app. The app will be hosted on Amazon.

However we are also wanting to build an eCommerce site in Wordpress or equivalent that sits on the root of the website, (eg www.mywebsite.com) with the app accessible through a "sign in" button. If the user presses the sign in button we want the location bar location to not change from the website they are on (www.mywebsite.com), even though the Wordpress site and Vue frontend may be stored on different locations/domains.

If the site is made in Wordpress, we can get another developer to do that webpage for us, while I work on the frontend. However we want the experience to be relatively seamless between connecting to the wordpress root site, clicking on the sign in button and being taken to the Vue frontend.

Is this possible? Do both sites have to be hosted on the same server for it to work (eg an Amazon EC2 server which hosts two webpages, the wordpress one and the vue one)?

Or can the wordpress put a link to the Vue frontend which doesn't change the web location to the user?

Or (worst case scenario) do we need to make both webpages in Vue as one Vue application, some pages requiring login to access and others not?

Thanks kindly for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in order to use Vue and WordPress together, you can either write 2 separate applications. One for the Frontend and one for the Backend, which is perfectly fine or you can simply write a WordPress Application with a Vue Theme.

This is how this could look like:

### WordPress Backend

You can use a normal WordPress backend, where you can build the architecture you want to. In addition, you need to set up the `REST-API` Wordpress provides. So this also means, just use plugins which support it. Otherwise, you would need to write custom endpoints. For example, Woocommerce would be a good e-commerce plugin, since it supports the API.

Learn more about it here: https://v2.wp-api.org/

Of course, you can host your WordPress installation on Amazon. Here is a good guide for that: https://aws.amazon.com/de/getting-started/tutorials/launch-a-wordpress-website/

> Notice: The `REST-API` is available in core since `4.7`. If you are using an older version you would need to install a plugin.

### WordPress Frontend

In order to create your Frontend, I'd recommend you to make a custom theme. Since you are just serving static files this can be done pretty easy. But still, you don't need to reinvent the wheel.

There's a really good starter theme out there: https://github.com/EvanAgee/vuejs-wordpress-theme-starter

It comes with all the stuff you need to get started and since it is just a theme, you can simply set up a usual WordPress hosting without handling Domains of multiple applications.

In order to get the data from the Backend, you would simply make calls to the `REST-API`. Here's an example: https://github.com/EvanAgee/vuejs-wordpress-theme-starter/blob/master/src/api/index.js

Comment: Thanks Orlandster for your help. So in your view, we can be running the Wordpress website on a separate server and then link to the Vue frontend running on another server with no problem? The theming between the sites isn't my main issue, it is having a wordpress site running on the root of our domain linking to a vue frontend running on another domain but not changing the location that the user sees in their location bar on their browser after clicking the sign in button on the wordpress root webpage.

Comment: @AlisterSmith So yeah you could run to separate applications. One Vue.js App in the Frontend and a WordPress Backend. And then communicate over the rest api. But I've meant in the above answer, was to run just one application. Just use a normal WordPress backend and then add a WordPress theme. As Theme, you could use the starter theme above. This is just a normal WordPress Theme using Vue.js. So all code you write would be in Vue.js and all the data from the server would still get passed over the server. But the advantage is the fact that it runs on one and the same server. (same Domain etc.)

Comment: Aha, that gives me a path to research down. Thanks very much Orlandster.